# How to get the name of most recently file in specific directory?

Tags: windows, cmd, filenames, dir

I try to get the most recently name-file in specific directory, with dir command:

```
dir /O:D|tail -3 |head -1
```

but I got this line:

```
11/23/2014  01:18 PM               393 2.32.5100-results.json
```

thanks

Comment: It works as expected here using cygwin head and tail. Which head and tail are you using? Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27089409/edit) to include the output from dir and the output you expect to see.

Comment: you want the filename only, right? Use `dir`'s parameter `/b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dir /b /a-d /o-d | head -1
```

And just for a native windows alternative

```
dir /b /a-d /o-d | cmd /v /c "set/p.=&&echo(!.!"
```

In both cases, execute a `dir` command, in bare format, without folders in date descending order and pipe the information into a

- `head` command that will retrieve the only the first line (the newest file)

or

- a `cmd` instance that will retrieve the first line (the newest file) and echo it to console